# Incorrect value while Making Frequency tables without Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried making a frequency table which returns frequency as percentages. And a function to display the table. All the Values are shown as zero and there is some error in the calculation of the percentage

I have tried changing the variable names and also tried hard coding the percentage but there is some problem while making of the table/dictionary

```
def freq_table(dataset, index):
    table_1 = {}
    total = 0

    for row in dataset:
        total += 1
        value = row[index]
        if value in table_1:
            table_1[value] += 1
        else:
            table_1[value] = 1

    table_percentages = {}
    for key in table_1:
        percentage = (table_1[key] / total) * 100
        table_percentages[key] = percentage 

    return table_percentages


def display_table(dataset, index):
    table_2 = freq_table(dataset, index)
    table_display = []
    for key in table_2:
        key_val_as_tuple = (table_2[key], key)
        table_display.append(key_val_as_tuple)

    table_sorted = sorted(table_display, reverse = True)
    for entry in table_sorted:
        print(entry[1], ':', entry[0])


display_table(ios_final, 12)
```

shows values like

> ```
> ('Weather', ':', 0)
> ('Utilities', ':', 0)
> ('Travel', ':', 0)
> ('Sports', ':', 0)
> ('Social Networking', ':', 0)
> ('Shopping', ':', 0)
> ('Reference', ':', 0)
> ('Productivity', ':', 0)
> ('Photo & Video', ':', 0)
> ('News', ':', 0)
> ('Navigation', ':', 0)
> ('Music', ':', 0)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Python 2, where dividing two integers results in an integer:

```
>>> 1/3, 2/3, 3/3, 4/3, 5/3, 6/3
(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2)
```

The same happens here:

```
percentage = (table_1[key] / total) * 100
```

If `table_1[key] < total` then the result of division will be *zero*.

You should convert one of them to a floating-point number:

```
total = float(calculate total here)
```

Or do `total = 0.0` and then increment it in the loop.

Division involving a floating-point number results in a floating-point number:

```
>>> 1/3., 2/3., 3/3., 4/3., 5/3., 6/3.
(0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 1.0, 1.3333333333333333, 1.6666666666666667, 2.0)
```

Comment: Thank You so much. I didn't realise that

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use `from __future__ import division` and your code should work as is.